# Binding a TextBlock 's Text property to current existing DataContext

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

For a  `TextBlock` control, I want the `Text` property to be depending on the current `DataContext`, and I will display some very nice formatted string-- depending on the type of the `DataContext`-- with an `IValueConverter` to properly convert the Text property.

How to do this?

Comment: @Clemens, it's TextBlock, question updated

Comment: Ok, then try `Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ...}}"`, which binds directly to the object in the DataContext.

Comment: @Clemens, woa, bulleye. Would you like to post it as an answer so that it can be upvoted and accepted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Binding without a Path (or with `Path=.`) binds directly to the object in the DataContext of the the TextBlock:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ...}}" />
```